# Is stoßlüften - quick exchange of air through windows actually more efficient than slow exchange through a wall ventilation fan?

Tags: thermodynamics, convection, humidity, fan, thermal-conduction

In German areas with near air-tight homes, it is recommended that full house ventilation is performed by stoßlüften - opening windows fully to exchange as much air as possible in shortest amount of time and then closing them.

The story goes that this furniture and walls retain more heat this way compared to other types of ventilation. Is there a physical explanation for why that would be the case? I learned about heat exchange by working with common aluminum heat sinks and I don't remember anything that would suggest that high speed fan bursts would remove heat slower than constant slow ventilation but maybe I'm wrong?